# Not able to see a Corporate email address box on the Cognito hosted login page

Tags: amazon-cognito, saml

Even after configuring AWS "IDP Identifier" for the federated providers, not able to  get the corporate email address box in the Cognito hosted login screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i was able to achieve the above requirement by adding multiple SAML IDP list with Cognito with "IdpIdentifiers" configured for each of them.

In case of only one SAML IDP configured, you will not see the corporate email address box in login screen.

Comment: Amazing that information like this cannot be found anywhere in the docs, thank you. It's also a good opportunity to say that the `Identifiers (optional)` should be the domain of the logged in user, otherwise it won't work. So if the user is some@one.com, the `Identifiers (optional)` should be `one.com` in order for it to work.

Comment: I agree, Identifiers should be mapped to provider domain.